# Автоматическое открытие HTML JS страничке в портейбл браузере

Tags: html, webbrowser, javascript

Всем привет!
Нужна гарантированная функциональность хтмл странички на всех ПК.
Один из вариантов - портейбл браузер (кстати, какой подойдет лучше всего?).
Как сделать, чтоб в один клик запустить страничку в портейбле, который лежит рядом?
Ну или как просто гарантировать открытие на всех Пк, знаю, что Qt умеет делать бинарники с вебкитом, но сам бинарник требует десятки библиотек, а заморачиваться с пересборкой Qt нет желания, да и результат по плавности интерфейса гораздо хуже.

Comment: чем вас не устраивает запуск с параметром url ?

Comment: @eicto и как это реализовать с относительными путями?

Comment: @SomeName с относительными путями чего ? Вот я хром например запускаю

    google-chrome index_ru.htm

из командной строки, и получаю открытый документ....